# Weird elseif behaviour

Tags: php, if-statement

I want to set a waiting time depending on the phase in which a user is. I just wanted to test this quick and put this:

```
function towait(){
    if ($query = mysql_query('select fase, lastone from users where id = "'.$_SESSION['id'].'"')){
        while($r[]=mysql_fetch_array($query));

        if ($r[0]['fase'] == 0) {
            $wait = 0;
        } elseif ($r[0]['fase'] == 1) {
            $wait = 300;
        } elseif ($r[0]['fase'] == 2) {
            $wait = 600;
        } elseif ($r[0]['fase'] == 3) {
            $wait = 900;
        } elseif ($r[0]['fase'] == 4) {
            $wait = 1500;
        } elseif ($r[0]['fase'] == 5) {
            $wait = 2100;
        } elseif ($r[0]['fase'] == 6) {
            $wait = 2700;
        } elseif ($r[0]['fase'] == 7) {
            $wait = 3600;
        } elseif ($r[0]['fase'] == 8) {
            $wait = 5400;
        } elseif ($r[0]['fase'] > 8) {
            $wait = 7200;
        } else {
            $wait = 0;
        }

        if((time() - $r[0]['lastone']) > $wait) {
            //go ahead
            $go = 1;
        } else {
            //you have to wait
            //I know this looks weird, but I just save the hour when OK to go as a string in the format "HHuMM"
            $go = date("H", ($r[0]['lastone'] + $wachten + 60)) . "u" . date("i", ($r[0]['lastone'] + $wachten + 60));
        }

        return $go;
    } else {
        $go = -1;

        return $go;
    }
}
```

The weird thing is, that everything works perfect until phase 7, but whenever the user is in phase 7, it stops working (the script doesn't let the user wait). The same for phase 8. In phase 9 and 9+ everything works again.

I know it sounds crazy (and the code is written poorly) but I was wondering what could cause this thing.

Comment: you could save about 20 lines of code by using an array

Comment: have you tried to do a var_dump of $r to see is fase 7 and 8 are present?

Comment: Since we don't see the way it is saved and know that `7` isn't being skipped or otherwise misinserted, it's hard to say. @Dagon - It could actually be computed.

Comment: @JaredFarrish correct, I never bothered to look at the numbers to closely, but its just * 300, odd the op decided on the method he did.

Comment: @Dagon - It's a little more complicated than that; each level past the third appears to add plus the previous, so it increments on some type of curve on the `fase` number.

Comment: @JaredFarrish arg, yup bad again. back to my own job.

Comment: @Dagon - LOL, I only got it because I spent *too long* reformatting the code.

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: Use `switch()` statement

Answer (score 1):

The most likely explination is that your session times out. This means that, when you return $_SESSION['id'] will be empty and it won't work.

You can increase the session time in php.ini: easiest to read a bblog that explains it all: http://prajapatinilesh.wordpress.com/2009/01/14/manually-set-php-session-timeout-php-session/

Comment: Session seems to be populated, so that's not the problem I guess. I used an array as Dagon suggested. Works fine now. Still don't know why the above won't work, but I care less now :)